# JAX-RS Exception mapper performance

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jax-rs

When using JAX-RS if the resources are strongly typed in order to control flow one typically uses Exception Mapper to generate the response. How much can this impact speed (does jersey/cxf/... do anything to prevent expensive stack unwinding) and what alternative we might have to generate the response if we want to keep the typed interface rather than a generic Response object?

Comment: exceptions should be exceptional. And their cost is negligible compared to the IO, serialization and DB access cost. I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: If you're worried about it, measure it. You'll always worry about it otherwise.